# FEM based solution to parabolic problem

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, parabolic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t - \Delta u = 0 &\text{ on } \Omega\times (0,T)\\u=0  &\text{ on } \partial \Omega\times (0,T) \\ u(x,0)=g(x) &\text{ on } \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $g$ is not zero on $\partial \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is smooth but not convex. Do you know of any FEM based fully discrete approach that is able to nicely handle the initial time singularity? On which assumptions on $g$, that do not imply setting it to $0$ on $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Have you tried something and gotten bad results?  I think the main thing you will need to worry about is using a time integrator that is L-stable.  And, at least intuitively, DG methods might work better than conventional FEM.

You are likely to get better answers on scicomp.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about FE methods, but even simple finite difference methods can deal with this singularity reasonably well.  Here is a solution of a 1D problem computed with a 3-point centered difference in space and a 2nd-order A-stable, L-stable method in time:

[image: TR-BDF2 solution]

The main thing you need to worry about is using an L-stable time integrator (or very small time steps).  Here is what happens with a method that isn't L-stable:

[image]

Notice the oscillations near the boundaries.  This numerical solution still converges to the correct one, but the convergence is very slow for small $t$.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint and the animations. I am mainly concerned about a priori error estimates: do you happen to have a reference that discusses theoretical guarantees of L-stable time integrators when it comes to problems exhibiting such a discontinuity?

Answering to what I have tried in this direction, I checked, among other sources, the reference book on the topic (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-33122-0) without finding anything.